# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, expo

app react-native ejected from expo

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\Mahdi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\17ff0ccf52fcac199760b507c7153494\transformed\material-1.5.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

     ERROR:C:\Users\Mahdi\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\17ff0ccf52fcac199760b507c7153494\transformed\material-1.5.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
```

=============

```
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
gradle-6.8.1
```

Comment: Erase the Android Studio cache and gradle cache and run it again.

Comment: I think your buildToolsVersion should be aligned with the compileSdk/targetSdk, try to use `30.0.2` or so

Comment: I did these things but to no avail, Do you have any other ideas?