# Android Studio | A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time i run any program in android studio, i get this error :
"Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable".
please help me solving this problem.

Comment: This question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71215689/1595451), but hasn't an answer. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.